# How can I use cors with Qwik?

Tags: cors, qwik

I'm stuck at using [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) in Qwik.

In Next, I would use this code snippet:

```
const cors = Cors({
  methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'HEAD'],
})

function runWithCors(req, res, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    callback(req, res, result => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result)
      }

      return resolve(result)
    })
  })
}
```

Yet in Qwik's Endpoints, I only have access to the `requestEvent`.

What should I do?

Comment: You can use express server to handle cors just like normal express application.

Comment: @HarshMangalam now i'm using Express for deploy Qwik Application, in `entry.express.tsx` file, and import cors above the file: `import cors from 'cors'` and use cors with this command: `app.use(cors());` but not working and give cors error on requests